# "To answer" versus "for answering"

Tags: word-choice, gerunds

Between these sentences, which one is correct/preferable?

> Answers are for answering the question, not commenting.

> Answers are to answer the question, not to comment it.

Is "for [gerund]" acceptable in some cases, for example in set phrases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both all right, but I would rephrase them a little to make them sound a little better, like so:

> Answers are for answering the question, not commenting *on it*.
>
> Answers are *meant* to answer the question, not <strike>to</strike> comment *on it*.

The first one, I think, is preferable over the second one. *"for [gerund]"* is perfectly acceptable in this case.